# How many zeros does a radical equation (eg, $X^{4/3}-5X^{2/3}+6=0$) have?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radical-equations

I want to know if there is a general rule that will give me the answer.
I'm not talking about crazy expressions under a radical, just simple
variables raised to a fractional exponent like:

$$X^{4/3}-5X^{2/3}+6=0$$

Comment: This is really a degree $4$ equation in $x^{1/3}$; since real cubic roots are unique, this is equivalent to solving $y^4-5y^2+6=0$, which has at most $4$ (real) solutions. (in fact, $y^4-5y^2+6=0 = (y^2-3)(y^2-2)$, so it has exactly four solutions..)

Comment: Note that Im not looking for the zeroes of this specific equation, Im trying to find out if theres a general algebraic property, like in the case of quadratic (2 zeros) and cubic (3 zeros).

Comment: @MaxVillafranca: are you talking about equations of this particular form $ax^{4/3}+bx^{2/3}+c=0$ or an arbitrary equation that contains fraction powers?

Comment: the most general form I can think of :
$ax^{\frac m n}+bx^{\frac p q}+c=0$.

Just like quadratic equations ALWAYS have 2 zeros (except double roots), is there a rule that always tell me how many zeros do rational equations have?

Answer (score 1):

Say that in your equation, the exponents of your unknown $x$ are fractions
$$\frac{m_1}{n_1},\ldots,\frac{m_k}{n_k}.$$

Let $N$ be the least common multiple of $n_1,\ldots,n_k$, and let $N = n_ic_i$. Then
$$\frac{m_i}{n_i} = \frac{m_ic_i}{n_ic_i} = \frac{m_ic_i}{N}.$$
That means that you can rewrite your equation as an equation in which every radical is an $N$th root. Letting $y=x^{1/N}$, you can then turn your equation into an equation in $y$ which has *no* radicals, just integral powers. That equation will be an equation of degree $M=\max\{c_1m_1,\ldots, c_km_k\}$, and so has at most $M$ solutions for $y$. When $N$ is odd, each solution for $y$ will give you a unique solution for $x$, yielding at most $M$ solutions for $x$.

If $N$ is even then at least one of the $n_i$ is even, which means that your $x$ must be nonnegative. So nonnegative values of $y$ will give one corresponding solution, but negative values of $y$ will not correspond to solutions of the original equation. In any case, there is at most one $x$ value per $y$-value, so again you get at most $M$ solutions for $x$.

Comment: (+1) I didn't think of it that way. (I just deleted my answer :p) It's elegant!

Answer (score 0):

For a case like this we can define $y=x^{\frac 23}$ and make the equation $y^2-5y+6=0$ which has two roots in $y$.  Then you can have either square root, so there will be four zeros.  You need to carefully specify the range of equations that is acceptable to get any simple rule.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "general rule" for solving all such equations. But your equation is a quadratic equation in disguise. Such questions mostly appear in pre-calculus exercises.

A rule of thumb is that you can make your equation easier by introducing new variables.

Since $x^{m/n}=(x^{1/n})^m$, you can write
$$
(x^{4/3})=(x^{1/3})^4,\quad (x^{1/3})^2
$$
so that your equation becomes
$$
(x^{1/3})^4-5(x^{1/3})^2+6=0\ \tag{1}
$$

Now if you introduce a **new** variable $y=x^{1/3}$, your equation becomes
$$
y^4-5y^2+6=0\tag{2}
$$
which looks simpler since there is no "radical" (fraction powers) anymore.

But this is still not easy: it is of power $4$.

But if you observe that $y^4=(y^2)^2$, (2) is the same as
$$
(y^2)^2-5y^2+6=0\tag{3}
$$
where if you introduce another **new** variable $w=y^2$, you have a quadratic equation
$$
w^2-5w+6=0
$$
which can be solved easily since $w^2-5w+6=(w-2)(w-3)$.